# How to fix parsing error expected error for the react code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

below is my code which i am trying to export it from a file and it gives me error parsing error type expected.

```
export const Content = (user: user) => (
  <> //i get error here
      <span>
          {user.name}
      </span>
      <span>{user.phone}</span>
  </>
);
```

below is my where i use this

```js
import {content} from '...'

function Parent() {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <Tooltip content={Content(user)}/>
        </Wrapper>
    );
}
```

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Can you copy/paste the whole, specific error message. Also, your import is using lower case, but the export has uppercase.

Comment: Maybe it's typescript saying that you should provide type schema for `user`

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript is a case-sensitive language

Use the same word carefully in uppercase and lowercase letters.

**C**ontent or **c**ontent